# Can a broken processor break anything else in a laptop?

Tags: laptop, cpu, motherboard

I have a [Dell Inspiron N5110](http://www.techradar.com/reviews/pc-mac/laptops-portable-pcs/laptops-and-netbooks/dell-inspiron-15r-n5110-985146/review) laptop with an [Intel® Core™ i5-2410M](http://ark.intel.com/products/52224) processor. I am interested in buying an i5-2430M processor on eBay for a friend but I need to test it on my laptop. The problem is that the seller has no feedback so I can't trust him but this also means that the price is much lower than normal.

The processor he sends me might be faulty so I have an important question:

**Can a faulty (in any way) processor break anything else in my laptop?**

*I know how to install it / apply thermal paste / not bend the pins / protect against static discharge so you can take this out of consideration.*

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in theory it could break your machine; it's circuitry, so it could cause a short! I've had this happen to me (at least, this was my opinion, the techy person I spoke to at a computer shop (sales) and a computer repair technician). Don't get me wrong, I'm not implying it's likely (and IMO it's pretty rare), but it is possible to cause damage to the board or *maybe* some components of the board).

Comment: Yeah, I'd say possible but rare.  Probably less likely than causing damage due to a screwdriver slip.

Comment: Totally agree Daniel,... we didn't believe it either but, it was the most probable cause!

Answer (score 0):

No, you will be safe as long as you install it properly.